# Java - Is it possible to call a stored procedure with varbinary out parameter ~10k bytes and null in parameters

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I've seem to have run across a limitation with JPA / Hibernate and available SQL Server drivers. (The two drivers I know of are jTDS and Microsoft's driver).

My requirement is call a stored procedure that:

1. has an out parameter of type varbinary(max) that is set with ~10k bytes AND
2. has two in parameters with default null value. Only one of the two parameters can have null value when called. I need the second one to have a non-null value.

Here's the procedure signature:

```
procedure [dbo].[pTest]

  @outParam varbinary(max) out

 ,@optParam1 varchar(max) = null

 ,@optParam2 varchar(max) = null 

 -- optParam1 or optParam2 can be null. But both cannot be null.
```

Ideally, I would like to use Spring Data JPA with jTDS to do this. But jTDS fails 1 b/c it truncates at 8k bytes. It passes 2 b/c I don't have to specify params with default values.

Using Microsoft's driver, 1 passes (AFAIK). 2 fails b/c I have to specify params up to the non-null value. If I don't, then I get index out of range. But if I specify the optParam1, I have to give it a non-null value per Hibernate. If I give it a non-null value, the stored procedure complains b/c it has a rule that optParam1 and optParam2 cannot both have a non-null value.

Is it possible to meet my requirements using Spring Data JPA / JPA? I have to work within these requirements. So if not supported using JPA, are there any alternatives to doing this in Java?

Comment: JPA (or better said your JPA provider) has nothing to do with it, it simply relays to JDBC CallableStatement. All is down to your JDBC driver. To solve it for using SQLServer driver you could pass in some "special" varchar that is interpreted as null internally.

Comment: I cannot change the stored procedure. It's developed by a third party and I don't have permissions to change it (nor will the third party provider change it). So, passing in some "special" `varchar` will not work. Also, doesn't the JPA provider still play a role here in the sense that it requires a non-null value to be specified? If I could specify null for the parameter, I could meet my requirements.

Comment: and why can't you specify null through the JPA API? What happens? Provider I use allows nulls as parameter values.

Comment: Spring Data JPA appears to be using Hibernate as the JPA provider. Well, I was thinking it was a JPA provider issue b/c I get similar error using both jTDS & Microsoft drivers. Here's the error when using Microsoft: `o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [pTest]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 2.` & here's the error using jTDS: `o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [pTest]
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #3 has not been set.`